# Why are my images broken when loaded via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have just uploaded my first 'website' (html+js) to a web server, and my images that are loaded via JavaScript are suddenly broken. (They worked on my local computer.)

I used relative paths (no path at all, since the images are in the same folder as .html and .js files). Static images that are encoded directly in html file are showing, but those loaded dynamically, via JavaScript do not show up. Any ideas why?

---

Sorry, I thought this could be something general, independent of JS. My very simplified piece of code for showing images:

```
$("#show_image").click(function(){
            $('#test1').append('<img src="a.jpg">');
        });
```

'show_image' is a button, #test1 is a div

Comment: Sorry, but we can't help without seeing your code and perhaps the relevant HTML.

Comment: btw. i used 000webhost.com for host

Comment: nope. (how can we come up with ideas if you don't show us what you did?)

Comment: problem is on line 42

Comment: Is this code inside a `$(document).ready()`?  Or, located after the `#show_image` object in your HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has similar problem, I've found the bug in my solution, it wasn't easy to find.

The server I used has CASE SENSITIVE file system, and my image's real file names were e.g. "a.JPG", instead of "a.jpg" as in code! Of course, this wasn't a problem on my local, case-insesitive file system, only on server.

I had no idea that server file systems could be case sensitive, now I know... :)

Comment: So your problem is solved now? If so close this question by marking your answer as accepted. Windows machines are generally case insensitive where as unix machines generally are not. But http servers can add exceptions to this.

Comment: If you read the URL specification (for instance) it says that URLs are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest montioring the resource loading problem in the Net panel in FireBug. Maybe it's a problem of calculating path, or permission problem in remote host.

Answer (score 0):

problem is you are missing a quote in your .append()

Comment: this wasn't the original problem, i copied it incorrectly here, fixed now, sorry